# No such file or directory - Handling Special Characters

Tags: java, special-characters

### Inroduction

A client is complaining that specific files cannot be processed that contain special characters such as "García" with an accented í. On my own machine and my own server everything works fine using the same filenames.

Therefore I suspect it could be an OS/filesystem/configuration/JVM issue.

**Overview of App Steps:**

1. is to download them and write them to disk from the pop3 server.
2. Process files and move them plus other stuff.

### Questions

1. How can I deal with this without change the file names?
2. If I do have to change the names, is there a library to do it?

### Stacktrace

```
2016-06-02 15:05:29.178 - [MapperUtils ] - [ERROR] - emailmonitoring.services.mappers.MapperUtils
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tomcat/data/inbox/1464710346000_03c2eef8-f224-4b45-9a2f-d5aade3e642a/Garc??a.pdf (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120) ~[na:1.6.0_45]
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyFile(FileUtils.java:1138) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.doCopyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1428) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1389) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
        at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyDirectory(FileUtils.java:1261) ~[commons-io-2.4.jar:2.4]
```

Comment: What's your actual question? If you can change the file name? Don't see why not

Comment: @wade, Actually if I don't want to change the name what could I do?

Comment: Well you can't control how their OS acts, so you can't do anything if you don't want to change the name. One suggestion if you're alright with altering special characters is you could put in the HTML code or something though, I'm pretty sure you can't "escape" non-english characters as you describe

Comment: Where/how does the code that throws the error get the file name?

Comment: @Andreas , that's a good question. It gets it from the database. So if the database does not support those character sets it would also cause a problem. I have to ask them that to check their oracle db.